# What are the special properties of adjunctions that generate polynomial monads

Tags: category-theory, monads

The subject of [polynomial monads](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.4931.pdf) is well trodden.  We know that every monad is generated by an adjunction.  What are the special properties of any adjunction that generates a polynomial monad?

Comment: Every adjunction for which the left and right adjoints are polynomial functors will induce a polynomial monad. I imagine the converse is also true.